# Determining how much data is needed for statistical significance of a percentage difference between two points?

Tags: statistical-significance

Imagining the following situation where A/B are independent results:

- A is a 51% result, given N datapoints
- B is a 50% result, given M datapoints

how many data points (ie N and M) do you need to have confidence that the difference between A/B is statistically significant?

Comment: Are you after an analytic solution? If not, I recommend browsing the site (and the internet) for power calculations for the two sample test. Like here: http://powerandsamplesize.com/Calculators/Compare-2-Proportions/2-Sample-Equality

Answer (score 3):

There are various sample size calculators you can use online and in various software for a two-sample proportions test.

Here's the calculation using Stata that suggests that you would need N=M=39,240 for a two-sided alternative test at conventional levels:

```
. power twoproportions .50 .51

Performing iteration ...

Estimated sample sizes for a two-sample proportions test
Pearson's chi-squared test 
Ho: p2 = p1  versus  Ha: p2 != p1

Study parameters:

        alpha =    0.0500
        power =    0.8000
        delta =    0.0100  (difference)
           p1 =    0.5000
           p2 =    0.5100

Estimated sample sizes:

            N =    78,480
  N per group =    39,240
```

Comment: @enderland Did this clarify things?